# Navigating through metadata in entreprise wiki

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, metadata

I'm a student and kind of new to SharePoint 2013. 
I'm trying to set up a knowledge base in SP 2013 for a small company.
I'm using an entreprise wiki to do this. ( Is this the correct way ? )
Now i want to add metadata to all my wiki pages and i want my users to be able to navigate through some metadata and if they click it, to see all coresponding pages with that metadata tagged.
Example : 
navigation :
- Sharepoint 2013
- Tagging
- Metadata
- installation
- Office 365
- Word
- lay-out
- installation
- Excel
- Acces
- Procedures
So for example if i click Office 365 => Word => installation , the page shows me all the documents linked with these metadata tags : Office 365,Word and installation.
Is this possible?
Thanks !!
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiki is definitely the correct choice.

[Manage metadata navigation might be what you're looking for...](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/configure-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-HA101820113.aspx)